# Angular 8 showing blank page with no errors

Tags: angular, angular8

I am developing an Angular 8 application that will login to a .Net Core Rest API using JWT Token Authentication.

When I start the application the application compiles successfully with no errors. However, when I open http://localhost:4200 a blank page appears.

Here is the `app-routing.module.ts` file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './_helpers';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',component:AppComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path: '**',redirectTo:''}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the `app.component.ts` file:

```js
import { Component ,ViewChild,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Sort} from '@angular/material';
import { Log } from './log';
import {MatPaginator,MatSort,MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

import { AuthenticationService } from './_services';
import { User } from './_models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  currentUser: User;
  public isViewable:boolean;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,private router: Router,private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){
    this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.currentUser = x);
  }

  dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<Log>();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['message','create_Date','log_Type'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort,{static:true}) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;

    this.apiService.getLogs().subscribe((res)=>{
      this.dataSource.data=res;    
    });
   }


   public onSortData(sort:Sort){
    let data=this.dataSource.data.slice();
    if(sort.active && sort.direction!==''){
      data=data.sort((a:Log,b:Log)=>{
          const isAsc=sort.direction==='asc';
          switch(sort.active){
            case 'message': return this.compare(a.message,b.message,isAsc);
            case 'create_Date':return this.compare(a.create_Date,b.create_Date,isAsc);
            case 'log_Type':return this.compare(a.log_Type,b.log_Type,isAsc);
            default: return 0;
          }
      });    
    }
    this.dataSource.data=data; 
   }

   private compare(a,b,isAsc){
    return (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()  ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1:-1);
   }

  public toggle():void{
    this.isViewable=!this.isViewable;

    this.apiService.getLogs().subscribe((res)=>{
      this.dataSource.data=res;
     });

    }

    logout() {
      this.authenticationService.logout();
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  }
```

Here is the `login.component.ts` file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'login.component.html' })
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    error = '';

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { 
        // redirect to home if already logged in
        if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) { 
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here is the `auth.guard.ts` file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

I expect to see the login page but a blank page appears after I type `ng serve` and open http://localhost:4200

Comment: What was the issue ? I guess you solved it by now and I get the same issue today...

Comment: here my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081118/12072898), hope it helps

Comment: Check your browser console, the cause of the error is usually displayed there.

Comment: @EmmanuelAliji there is no error in the console in my case. and no error from my API.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, this just happend to me and may help someone else:

- installed @nestjs/ng-universal `$ ng add @nestjs/ng-universal`
- the angular project I´m working on already had @nguniversal installed, I´ve uninstalled manually all I´ve found related to it.
- so when I´ve installed this new package, it modified the again /src/main.ts, wrapping twice the boostrap.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
});
```

This give me a blank page running `$ ng serve` with no error, no message, no nothing, just a white and nasty page.
After deleting one of the `document.addEventListener( ...` wrappers, it worked!

Comment: @guillefd, for newbie-ism reasons, I need a digest. So I should:

1) install with $ ng add @nestjs/ng-universal
2) add imports to app.module as shown at ng-universal repo
3) replace main.ts code for 
```document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
});```
Is that it? 

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: If this does not work, check your browser console. The error is usually displayed there.

Answer (score 3):

Recently  I faced the same issue in the chrome browser, after updating chrome version this issue fixed.
You can verify this issue related to the browser or not, by cross-checking in other browsers like IE or Safari.

**Edit:** Additional to this, please try by disabling some extensions in chrome. Make sure you restart the browser once you disabled the extensions. Once it is working enable required extensions.

Comment: This helped me more than the other answers. Actually found out it was OBS running in the background that caused my angular app just to appear as white. I assume it's something to do with rendering. The same issue on Edge, Chrome, and Brave (All Chromium based), Firefox seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is generally hard to identify. However, it is **probably** linked to an error in code which gets executed during application initiation. This most probably includes initiation of any kind of authentication module.

Check/debug your `app.module.ts` and all things called from there - like `APP_INITIALIZER`.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your 'AuthGuard'.Check whether its returning true. Since your default root has been protected and if it returns false then i think thats why your page is not loading.

Comment: I edited the question and added the AuthGuard file.Can you check the code again?

Comment: If you need more code just tell me and I will edit the question and write more code

Answer (score 1):

1.- Open tags. Check if you have the properly closed tags in the html files. In my case the problem was because in one component I had an extra `</div>`.

2.- Undeclared inputs. Check if you are trying to pass an input that is not declared in the component, for example `<app-component [var1]="123"> </app-component>`, in your component you must necessarily have the input declared `@Input () var1;`

3.- keys to print `{{}}` empty in some html file

4.- undeclared properties with angular tags. For example in a `<input [anyWord]>` where [anyWord] is not a valid entry

Answer (score 1):

You can also check to see if your selectors have been named correctly after refactoring

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an unsupported version of IE?

Try Chrome, a later IE or Firefox, etc. Alternatively, you can uncomment  the browser polyfills in polyfills.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
```

Answer (score 0):

I facing same issue so i just refresh page twice and that's works but you can try this,
in your routes if angular can't find any routes that you've typed on you shoul redirect to
`PageNotFoundComponent`, so create a component `PageNotFoundComponent` and redirect to that component because you don't handle at all other routes other then those that you specified

```
 {path: '**',redirectTo:''} // instead of this 
 {path: '**', redirectTo:'PageNotFoundComponent'} // add this
```

Or you may try this with `{ useHash: true }` in routerConfig and all routes will use `#/login` and you can use this just for development mode and when you want to publish you can remove this config `{ useHash: true }`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Sorry but I have tried both solutions but none of the solutions are working

Comment: If you need more code just tell me and I will edit the question and write more code

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just named the file `app.routing.ts` instead of `app-routing.module.ts`. By fixing that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with my code was I have used the keycloak installation config object as it is
i.e

```js
{
                "realm": "demo",
                "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth/",
                "ssl-required": "external",
                "resource": "local",
                "public-client": true,
                "confidential-port": 0,
                "clientId": "local"
}
```

But it was wrong, the correct one was as below:

{
url: "http://localhost:8180/auth/",
realm: "demo",
clientId:  "local"
}

Answer (score 0):

In my case in the template I had an all-wrapping container with ngIf="..." and its condition was false thus not a single line of html was rendered

Answer (score 0):

In my case, probably the localhost was active somehow. I searched for the port number in the files (e.g. : 4200) and changed it to another port number (e.g. 4201)

Answer (score -3):

Missing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your view? ([Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet))